# How to add TreeView to AvalonDock?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, prism, avalondock

I am using perfect library [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com) and would like to show TreeView inside docking layout. So my TreeView should be dockingable.

I cannot figured out how TreeView should be added to AvalonDock. For example, I have standard layout.

I've tried this old approach, however this code is not working as I'm using AvalonDock 2.0 and there is no `ResizingPanel`, `DockableContent`:

```
<avalonDock:ResizingPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <avalonDock:DockablePane>
            <avalonDock:DockableContent x:Name="fileFrame" Title="File List">
                <TreeView Name="fileTree"/>                        
            </avalonDock:DockableContent>
            <avalonDock:DockableContent x:Name="viewFrame" Title="View List">
                <TreeView Name="viewTree"/>
            </avalonDock:DockableContent>
        </avalonDock:DockablePane>
  </avalonDock:ResizingPanel>
```

***My goal is to have TreeView at the left side at start of program like in Visual Studio:***

[image]

**How to add TreeView to AvalonDock to see TreeView at start of MainWindow?**

**Edit:**

Now I can see TreeView in Visual Studio:
[image]

However, there is no TreeView in started program(just yellow screen):
[image]

**How to show TreeView with dummy data at the left side at start of program like in Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a control directly to the `LayoutAnchorablePane` - you have to wrap it in a `LayoutAnchorable`:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" >
    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="ToolsPane" DockHeight="150">
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    <TreeView Name="viewTree"/>
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
        </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

**Edit:**

If you want your treeview on the leftside, here a snippet with some dummy data:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager">
    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="ToolsPane" DockWidth="150">
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    <TreeView Name="viewTree">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="North America">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="USA" />
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Canada" />
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Mexico" />
                        </TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="South America">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Argentina" />
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Brazil" />
                            <TreeViewItem Header="Uruguay" />
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeView>
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane />
        </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Comment: it is really strange:), however I can see TreeView in Visual Studio, however if I run my proramm, then I cannot see TreeView. How to show TreeView in started program?

Comment: Anyway, I cannot see my TreeView in program, but TreeView can be seen  perfectly In Visual Studio. Please, see my updated question.